# Symmetric Behavior in "VLSI Chip Testing" Problem

Tags: algorithm, math

I am recently working on some algorithms learning, and I found this interesting question:

There are n supposedly identical VLSI chips that in principle are capable of testing each other. Each chip tests the other and reports whether it is good or bad. A good chip always reports accurately whether the other chip is good or bad, but the answer of a bad chip cannot be trusted. Thus, the four possible outcomes of a test are as follows:

Chip A says  Chip B says     Conclusion
B is good       A is good          both are good, or both are bad
B is good       A is bad            at least one is bad
B is bad         A is good          at least one is bad
B is bad         A is bad            at least one is bad

I still confuse with the following question:

- Show that if more than n/2 chips are bad, we cannot necessarily determine which chips are good using any strategy based on this kind of pairwise test. Assume that the bad chips can conspire to fool the the tester.

I searched online and most of the answers mentioned "symmetric behavior", and it is not possible to distinguish which one is good chip base on this behavior. I kind of feel this symmetric concept, but those answers all don't explain deeply why this only takes effect when more than n/2 chips are bad, which, in another word, those answer are not showing strong relationship with the fact "if more than n/2 chips are bad"

Can anyone help me out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would argue as follows:
Assume there are `n` chips, and among them `b` bad ones.
Every chip can be tested by `n-1` others. Among the outcomes, `n-b` are correct and `b` cannot be trusted.
An outcome of a test is considered correct, if the majority of the `n-1` tests, i.e. `(n-1)/2` are the same.
If now `b > n/2`, all tests of a specific chip could accidentally of by conspiracy give the same wrong answer, and this answer would be considered correct.

Comment: Thanks Reinhard! This is kind of making sense. However, in my mind, this sentence "An outcome of a test is considered correct, if the majority of the n-1 tests, i.e. (n-1)/2 are the same." might just actually be a valid "algorithm" which is correct when more than n/2 chips are good. Maybe there might be an other "undiscovered" algorithm which can find a good chip even when there are more than n/2 chips are bad.  A more convincing answer I expect might be: 
Assuming this is such an algorithm that can find a good chip when more than n/2 chips are bad, and then we deduce to a contradiction